# Is there any way to change layout direction within application based on language? (RTL if user select arabic, LTR if user select English)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

My Application must support Arabic(right to left direction) and English(left to right direction) language, I need to set UI and based on user select language from my application.

I am using Auto layout for User Interface.

My device language is say English and from my application user select Arabic, So my Flow,UI,Animations etc should be right to left.

Comment: Minimum iOS requirement?

Answer (score 2):

As a documentation says the iOS do it automatic.

> If you use base internationalization and Auto Layout, most of the user
>   interface will appear mirrored automatically for you.

You no need make changes with your layout. Auto layout just swap leading and trailing constraint.

For more info please look the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your UI components and set text alignment according to user language selection. Say make class MyLabel subclassing UILabel and where ever you are using UIlabel change its class TO MyLabel in Xib. Do so for other components.

Keep Leading And Trailing constraint equal so that left and right difference could not be separated.